# MVC3 - Getting to Grips with the DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC, so bear with me...

I've got my new form\view working (Creating and Adding a client)
But now I want to get the user so specifiy the Country where the new client is from A drop downlist. But im to sure how I to do this?

ViewModel

```
public class ClientNew
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    //New
    public IEnumerable<CountryList> Country{ get; set; }
}

public class CountryList
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller
(This is where is may be wrong, and is this the best way to do it?)

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var cl= new List<CountryList>();
    cl.Add(new CountryList(){Id = "abcd",Name = "UK"});
    cl.Add(new CountryList() { Id = "abce", Name = "USA" });
    var model = new ViewModels.ClientNew();
    model.Country= cl;
    return View("New", model);
}
```

View (not sure how to plumb this in)

```
Html.DropDownList("Id" ??????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you will set up your dropdown on the property Id. This will be the current value selected in the dropdown when you POST to your form. The data that will be used for the dropdown is a SelectList called Countries that exists in your model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.Countries)
```

Your view model will have your Id, Name and Countries properties plus whatever else you need.

```
public class ClientNewViewModel {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SelectList Countries { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller you need to pass the model to the view. You will need to populate the Countries SelectList. Keep in mind you will need to populate this value when you POST and fail validation as well.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
     var model = new ClientNewViewModel();

     model.Countries = new SelectList(service.GetCountries(),
         "Id", "Name"); // set up what properties are used for id/name of dropdown

     return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(ClientNewViewModel model)
{
    if( !ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        model.Countries = new SelectList(service.GetCountries(),
            "Id", "Name");

        return View(model);
    }

    // redirect on success
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could have IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries on your ViewModel and then just do a Linq projection in the Action to set it. IMO this is a better approach because it is refactorable and doesn't rely on magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.DropDownList("Id", 
                  Country.Select(x => new SelectListItem 
                                          { 
                                              Text = x.Name, 
                                              Value = x.Id 
                                          }));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good blog post on the in's and out's of how to do this here -> [http://277hz.co.uk/Blog/Show/10/drop-down-lists-in-mvc--asp-net](http://277hz.co.uk/Blog/Show/10/drop-down-lists-in-mvc--asp-net-)